# Unwanted margin on main background image

Tags: css

So i'm having trouble getting rid of a small margin that appears on the background of my main index page:  This is the [upper corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z83Kl.png) of it, i have a fixed navbar on top that does not share the same problem, but the background image below wont fill the entire space.

This is the css code that i'm using:

```css
.indexmain{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: url(images/main-screen.jpg) no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Apparently there's no inheritance issue from any other asset, utilizing a fixed position with 'left:0' didn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding margin-left: 0px; in the images class

Comment: Float: left;? Check if anything outside of the class is making the margin happen.

Comment: I had forgotten to upload the normalize stylesheet, it was inheriting the margin from the browser styling, just another classic case of a rookie mistake. Thanks @GoofBall101, really appreciate it.